# How to update server settings without recreating docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, azerothcore

I followed the official [installation guide for AzerothCore using Docker containers](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker) and I would like to know if there is a way to update the server settings without recreating the docker containers.

If the containers has to be recreated to apply new settings, how can I prevent my characters from being deleted when recreating the docker containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [official documentation says in the FAQ section](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#how-can-i-start-stop-create-and-destroy-my-containers), you don't have to *recreate* your containers.

You can simply start/stop them using:

- `docker-compose stop` to stop your containers
- `docker-compose start` to start again your containers

Those are different than using `down` and `up` which will destroy/recreate them.

If you simply change the `worldserver.conf` configuration **content** then it's enough to stop/start the containers. If you want to change the **location** of such configuration files, then you have to **recompile** (i.e. destroying/recreating containers of the `worldserver` and `authserver`).

Comment: Does starting and stopping the container actually apply the new configuration? The section in the FAQ is not very clear regarding updating the conf expect that you can run "docker-compose up" after updating the .env file.

Comment: @Jimmy if you simply change the `worldserver.conf` configuration **content** then it's enough to stop/start the containers. If you want to change the **location** of such configuration files, then you have to recompile (i.e. destroying/recreating containers of the `worldserver` and `authserver`).

Comment: Okey, thanks for clearing that up for me! Please include that in your answer as well.

Comment: @Jimmy done, please mark my answer as resolving or let us know if you need further help with this issue.